# How To Make Validations With Requests In Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 8.
I am trying to validate inputs for creating users in the store method of my controller using requests.
Store method of my user controller
UserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\UserCreateRequest;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function store(UserCreateRequest $request)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => Hash::make($request->input('password')),    
        ]);

        return response($user, 201);
    }

   
}
```

UserCreateRequest.php is the file I used to make validation.
UserCreateRequest.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;



class UserCreateRequest extends FormRequest

{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|min:3|max:25',
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ];
    }
}
```

But the problem is I get this error

```
{
    "message": "Method Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator::validateRequierd does not exist.",
    "exception": "BadMethodCallException",
    "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php",
    "line": 1395,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php",
            "line": 554,
```

Comment: Looks all good, but it seems you made a typo somewhere because it tries to call `validateRequierd` and not `validateRequired`. You probably wrote `requierd` somethere in your validation rules.

Comment: Found it. Cannot believe it made me scratch my head so much. 
Use it answer it with this. And I will accept your answer. @codedge

Comment: Set `password` as required field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks all good, but it seems you made a typo somewhere because it tries to call `validateRequierd` and not `validateRequired`. You probably wrote `requierd` somethere in your validation rules.